# Is there any way to keep variable value in recursive function in SML?

Tags: sml

```
fun temp(x) = 
let val a = x
in if a mod (x-1) = 0 then x
   else temp(x-1)
end;
```

this is example Standard ML code.

What I want to know is that 
for example user call temp(10); then a = 10 and the temp(x-1) is called.

then the variable 'a' will change to 9. Can I keep it as 10 in Standard ML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function contains `val a = x`, then for any invocation of `temp(x)`, the value of `a` will be equal to the value of `x`. If you want to remember the value of `a` from a previous invocation when you recurse, you need to pass it around as a parameter like this:

```
fun temp_helper x a =
  if a mod (x-1) = 0 then x
  else temp_helper (x-1)

fun temp x = temp_helper x x
```

You could also make the helper function an inner function. If you do that, you can actually remove `a` as a parameter and instead close over `a` like this:

```
fun temp x =
let
  val a = x
  fun helper x =
    if a mod (x-1) = 0 then x
    else helper (x-1)
in
  helper x
end
```